# how to convert reduce to map in Es6

Tags: node.js

```js
    const array =    [36,11,19,17,22,37,12,15,10,4,30,14,10,15,35,11,8,25,15,25,15,47,12,16,33,13,19,20,21,20,21,29,32,38,38,21,22,0,18,39,0,29,26,32,33,39,31,45,36,35,45,28,40,37,10,12,11,8,8,9,4,11,5,9,7,5,9,30,15,40,29,38,36,42,30,10,20,21,30,20,17,36,31,50,11,26,40,33,44,32,29,4,27,36,10,10,15,10,6,22,7,12,5,4,10,12,19,9,15,22,2,4,6,18,7,6,3,25,11,5,1,39,13,18,18,27,28,1,7,19,26,13,23,5,42,41,27,38,22,43,43,37,37,23,42,47,42,16,34,34,32,14,45,18,36,36,3,18,24,3,3,4,1,4,3,7,3,2,4,5,2,2,4,6,3,5,3,2,2,1,23,19,24,16,24,19,14,21,22,33,17,16,26,12,27,23,12,23,22,20,1,20,4,7,6,33]; 
    const n = array.length; 
    const mean = array.reduce((a,b) => a+b)/n;   
    const s = Math.sqrt(array.map(x => Math.pow(x-mean,2)).reduce((a,b) => a+b)/(n-1)); 
    console.log(s);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?.

Comment: I am getting error reduce not a function error in node js. So i want convert reduce function to map. I am try to calculate standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder if this might help you but can you please tell us by details what are you trying to do ?

```
    const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```

Comment: I don't want use reduce function here.

Comment: let me know how i can help you with map can you please clarify your question please ?

Comment: I want convert this reduce function in this line into map const s = Math.sqrt(array.map(x => Math.pow(x-mean,2)).reduce((a,b) => a+b)/(n-1));

Comment: Any way thanks for the help. I figured it out.
const n = array.length;
function total(arr) {
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)) return;
  let sum=0;
  arr.forEach(each => {
    sum+=each;
  });
  return sum;
};
const mean = total(array)/n;
const powerCalc = array.map(x => Math.pow(x-mean,2));
const s = Math.sqrt(total(powerCalc)/(n-1));
console.log(s);